# curl large file as POST request

Tags: python, unix, curl

I have a number of ~10MB xml files on a local computer. For each file, I need to send it to a remote server for processing. The way I attempted to do this was by using `curl` to POST to a function:

```
curl MyIP -d @my_file.xml
```

Where `MyIP` is the url of the function that does the xml processing. However, this seems to be problematic, as most of the POST data is cut off due to some limitation (though I'm not sure what this limitation is).

What would be the suggested way to send a ~10MB file to a remote server for text processing? Could I set up the above way using curl & a function to work? Should I set up an FTP and then run a cron job on the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use POST

```
curl -X POST -d @my_file.xml http://user:pass@myhost/
```

By default curl uses "GET" verb. You have to specify the HTTP verb using option `-X`

Comment: Thank you -- I think my problem now is that the file is not properly url-encoded, so it cuts off on any non-valid character, such as on `SAM&#39;S CLUB`. How would I url-encode this POST request?

Comment: The man page for curl says `-d (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server...` so I'm pretty sure the `-X POST` is unnecessary.