# POST 4GB file from shell using cURL

Tags: shell, curl

I try to post a file with a filesize of 4GB to a REST API.

Instead of uploading a file with this size, cURL POSTs a file with Content-Length: 0.

```
curl -v -i -d @"/work/large.png" -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" http://localhost:8080/files
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fcafc00aa00
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fcafc00aa00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying localhost...
* Connected to localhost (localhost) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /files HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Authorization: bearer XXX.XXX.XXX
> x-user-token: bearer XXX.XXX.XXX
* upload completely sent off: 5 out of 0 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Date: Thu, 02 Jan 2014 14:55:46 GMT
Date: Thu, 02 Jan 2014 14:55:46 GMT
< ETag: "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
ETag: "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
< Location: http://localhost:8080/files/66032e34-9490-4556-8495-fb485ca12811
Location: http://localhost:8080/files/66032e34-9490-4556-8495-fb485ca12811
* Server nginx/1.4.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.4.1
Server: nginx/1.4.1
< Content-Length: 0
Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive
```

Using files with a smaller size will work as expected.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user1  wheel  4403200000  2 Jan 15:02 /work/large.png
```

Why does the upload fail? And, how to correctly upload such a file?

Cheers.

Comment: Maybe you need `-X POST`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11164871/1542000

Comment: Thanks Karl, but this doesn't help. IMHO cURL uses POST as default when specifying -d.

Comment: Try `--data-binary` instead of `-d`. `-d` defaults to `--data-ascii`, which won't work well on a *binary* PNG image.

Comment: `--data-binary` works perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey, @Nils! Perhaps you could consider accepting one of the answers here? This would help out others users, as it lets them know what worked for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To upload large binary files using CURL you'll need to use `--data-binary` flag.

In my case it was:

```
 curl -X PUT --data-binary @big-file.iso https://example.com
```

**Note:** this is really an extended version of @KarlC comment, which actually is the proper answer.

Answer (score 28):

I think you should consider using `-T` option instead of `--data-binary`. The `--data-binary` loads the entire file into memory (curl 7.47). At best it is slow, at worst the OOM killer will reply with a `Killed` message.

```
curl -XPOST -T big-file.iso https://example.com
```

Comment: I'm confused. You suggest using `-T` instead of `--data-binary`,  and the answer below by @jb. says that `--data-binary` is the right way to do it?

Comment: If the client has enough memory to hold the file in memory then `--data-binary` _could_ be the "right way to do it".

Comment: What does the -T flag do?

Comment: This question is 4 yours old, but the -T flag stands for transfer, as in transfer or upload a file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that the connection is not timing out ?
Check [CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS has a length or size limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344528/curlopt-postfields-has-a-length-or-size-limit)
Check [Can't post data to rest server using cURL with content length larger than 1MB](https://drupal.org/node/1862478)

But based on my research all I can say, is issue is at server side. Now it could be memory issue (Buffer size related ), timeout issue... and quite a lot depends on the platform you are using on server side. So, provide some details about serverside and some log output...especially try to capture the error log.

Comment: The server side actually doesn't get a request entity. Even if I change to a remote server, there is no network activity at all. I also tried to upload a file using Jersey, which works fine with the same server backend.

Comment: Can you try with a smaller file first and see if it works? Say something like, less than 2 mb. If that works we are sure your framework is working in some form. Also, let me know the content of access log (or its equivalent) with both < 2 mb and 4 GB file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the curl was consuming way too much memory as the file size... I noticed that the response was the issue (maybe a memory leak in curl or bash?) and I solved it by directing the curl output to a file:

```
curl {{command arguments and url}} > curl_response.data
```

that solved the issue of curl using up too much memory...